# Parody of 'Consider the ant'

Tags: identification-request, poetry

This half-remembered poem, from what I can recall, was written by someone who worked for the New Statesman or the Spectator in the 1970s.

The opening part is:

> They say consider the ant O thou sluggard, go to its ways and be wise
>
> Well, I've considered the ant and I'm buggered why it thinks it's as good as us guys
>
> I'd rather consider the lily...

What is the rest?

Comment: Is the answer below correct? If so (it certainly seems a very strong match for your description), you can accept it to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

‘Go to the ant’ by **Stanley J. Sharpless**:

> ‘Go to the ant, thou sluggard;
> Consider her ways, and be wise,’
> Well, I’ve been to the ant, and I’m buggered
> If I think it’s one up on us guys;
> All that rushing about is damn silly,
> (And uneconomic, I bet),
> I'd rather consider the lily,
> It's got Solomon beat—and no sweat.
>
> <sub>Stanley J. Sharpless (1977). ‘[Go to the ant](https://archive.org/details/newoxfordbookofe00amis/page/278/mode/2up)’. In *The New Statesman*, 30 September 1977. In Kingsley Amis, ed. (1978), *The New Oxford Book of English Light Verse*, Oxford University Press, p. 278.</sub>

The first two lines quote Proverbs 6:6 in the Authorized Version; according to Proverbs 1:1 this is one of the “proverbs of Solomon”. The last two lines are an allusion to Matthew 6:28: “Consider the lilies of the field, how they grow; they toil not, neither do they spin.”